# Pass non-clonable, non-static object to thread requiring static data

Tags: rust, imgui

I'm using the ImGui Rust binding, and I have a big problem:
I need to access the 'system' variable of the window from another thread: this variable grants control to several functions e.g. changing window size.
I need to access this variable in the `.build(ui, || { })` block. This code is taken (but shortened) from the example at: https://github.com/Gekkio/imgui-rs/blob/master/imgui-examples/examples/hello_world.rs

```
use imgui::*;

mod support;

fn main() {
    let system: support::System = support::init(file!());
    system.main_loop(move |_, ui| {
        Window::new(im_str!("Hello world"))
            .size([300.0, 110.0], Condition::FirstUseEver)
            .build(ui, || {
                // Do stuff with the UI here.
            });
    });
}
```

This is a problem, since the event loop function (That is the lambda in the .build() function) must use 'move' to pass ownership of all variables, and thus they essentially require a static lifetime.

I've came across several posts with people that almost have the same problem, but my data is non-static, and non-copyable. That is where the headache occurs.

Since I need a global state as well, it would be a good idea to wrap this variable in a struct. I managed to make it so that the struct can be passed to the thread without problems, but the 'system' variable still refuses to work.

Here are some examples of the scenarios that I've tried:

```
struct State {
    system: Option<support::System>
}

fn main() {
    let state = Arc::new(State {
        system: Some(support::init(file!()))
    });

    ERROR -> state.system.unwrap().main_loop(move |x: &mut bool, ui: &mut Ui| {});
}
```

This doesn't work, for the following reason:

> cannot move out of an `Arc` move occurs because value has type
> `std::option::Option<support::System>`, which does not implement the
> `Copy` traitrustc(E0507) main.rs(31, 5): consider borrowing the
> `Option`'s content

Borrowing won't work, so this is definitely annoying. Then we just store a reference to **support::System** in the struct, and that will solve it, right?

```
struct State<'a> {
    system: Option<&'a support::System>
}

fn main() {
    let system = support::init(file!()); 
    let state = Arc::new(State {
        ERROR -> system: Some(&system)
    });
}
```

This doesn't work because the Rust compiler thinks that the data won't live long enough (I know it will, but the compiler can't determine it properly)

> `system` does not live long enough borrowed value does not live long
> enoughrustc(E0597) main.rs(59, 1): `system` dropped here while still
> borrowed main.rs(25, 17): argument requires that `system` is borrowed
> for `'static`

Okay, that sounds reasonable. Then just use a **Box<>** to allocate it on the heap and forget about the whole problem.

```
struct State {
    system: Box<support::System>
}

fn main() {
    let state = Arc::new(State {
        system: Box::new(support::init(file!()))
    });

    let state1 = state.clone();
    let system1 = &state1.system;
    ERROR -> system1.main_loop(move |x: &mut bool, ui: &mut Ui| {
        Window::new(im_str!("Main"))
        .flags(WindowFlags::NO_DECORATION | WindowFlags::NO_RESIZE)
        .position([0f32, 0f32], Condition::Always)
        .build(ui, || {
            let state = state.clone();
            THIS WORKS! -> let system = &state.system;
            // Do stuff with the 'system' variable.
        });
    });
}
```

This results in an error with a slightly more complex type:

> cannot move out of `**system1` which is behind a shared reference move
> occurs because `**system1` has type `support::System`, which does not
> implement the `Copy` traitrustc(E0507)

What? I'm trying to access a reference, I don't want to copy anything.

I am out of ideas. I have pretty much the exact same code in C++ and that works without problems, because C++ doesn't care about variable ownership: you can pass around the 'state' pointer as much as you want.

I'd also like to add that I've tried the same **Arc<>** scenario by wrapping the 'State' in a **Arc<Mutex<>>**. It results in one of the same errors that the examples trigger. I've also tried to work with a static version of the struct, but that yields problems that it's immutable, and I believe that it threw the same ownership errors.

I have a feeling that this is very easy to solve, but it does require some (advanced) experience in the Rust borrowing mechanic. I am new to Rust (Less than a week of hobby experience) and I can grasp a lot of concepts, but I essentially need to avoid the ownership mechanism here, since the data must be globally shared.

I hope that an experienced Rustacean knows the solution to this! Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The `System` struct is part of the example code, not part of the framework. And [the `main_loop()` method takes ownership of `self`](https://github.com/Gekkio/imgui-rs/blob/d5be602f73c51896838318958cd6c930f18cc8c3/imgui-examples/examples/support/mod.rs#L86), so there is simply no way to use the `system` variable in any other way, since you've already given it away. I guess you just need to modify the example in a way to allow shared access to whatever part of the `System` struct you need.

Comment: Indeed, the System struct is part of the included mod.rs file. I was hoping I could leave that code alone, especially since I also can't really believe that it is impossible to simply pass a pointer around.

I will try to edit the System struct to use Box<> for it's members. That will probably do the trick.

Comment: Mutable global state is exactly what Rust is trying to steer you away from. Are you very sure you can't architect your code better to avoid needing it in the first place?

Comment: @Thomas With GUI programming, you generally have at least _some_ global mutable state, and that's unavoidable.

Comment: @Thomas I agree that a global state is not desirable. However, the event loop of a window must be able to interface with the window itself. This is unfortunately impossible without some sort of global state (Or passing a reference to the window, but I cannot do that here).

Comment: @admbot You can pass references around. Your problem is that you are giving ownership of `system` to the `main_loop()` method, and then try to use it later. You can't have your cake and eat it. You need to verify whether the `main_loop()` method really needs ownership of everything in `System`, or whether some bits inside that structure could be wrapped in an `Arc<>` or an `Arc<Mutex<>>`, so you can pass references of these bits elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that I was looking in the wrong direction: I was trying to access stuff from the top of **main()** in the **.build(ui, || {})** block, but what I should have been doing was retrieving that info from **system.main_loop()** as parameter. A global state with trivial variables should still be done as I attempted previously, but when you need a reference to window internals, you do need a different solution.

I made the following changes:
In mod.rs (This file is included in the linked ImGui examples), change the signature of **F** in **main_loop()** to pass a **&Display**:
`pub fn main_loop<F: FnMut(&mut bool, &Display, &mut Ui) + 'static>(self, mut run_ui: F)`

Then in said function, change the call to **run_ui()** to pass a reference of the display variable. This function already possesses all of these internal variables, so you can directly access it: `run_ui(&mut run, &display, &mut ui);`
After doing so, you can now edit your lambda to **main_loop** to receive this new parameter. You can then do exciting things with the window context!

```
system.main_loop(move |x: &mut bool, display: &glium::Display, ui: &mut Ui| {
    let gl_window = display.gl_window();
    let window_size = gl_window.window().inner_size();

    Window::new(im_str!("Main"))
        .position([0f32, 0f32], Condition::Always)
        .size([window_size.width as f32, window_size.height as f32], Condition::Always) // <- We can now use window internals here!
        // etc, build your window as usual
});
```

Thanks for your comments guys, and I hope that this may help others in the future!